# createjs flash cc video not loading inside stage

Tags: createjs

i followed the ticket . 
[Easiest way to load a video in CreateJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28927434/easiest-way-to-load-a-video-in-createjs)
but the problem is it loads video outside my createjs stage . for easy understanding i have uploaded the code here :
http://graphicscoder.org/stackover/video/yes.html

```
<script>

var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    exportRoot = new lib.yes();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);

var videoDom = $('<video width="320" height="240" autoplay><source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>').appendTo(document.body)[0];
var cjsVideo = new createjs.DOMElement(videoDom);
stage.addChild(cjsVideo);

    stage.update();
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(24);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

at last i found the answer myself you can load video in createjs canvas without jquery/js

just paste the code in  flash cc

```
/* js
video = document.createElement(‘video’);
video.src = ‘http://graphicscoder.org/video/small.mp4’;
video.autoplay =true;
video.controls=true;
video.volume = 0;
var Video = new createjs.Bitmap(video);
stage.addChild(Video);
*/
```

to get source: http://graphicscoder.org/my-createjs/load-video-in-canvas-createjs/